# Splitting on ; then on =, having issues using String.Split, regex required

Tags: c#, regex

```
"key1"="value1 http://www.example.com?a=1";"key2"="value2 http://www.example.com?a=2";
```

I need to split the above line 2 times, the first time it is the comma character ; and the second time on the = sign.

It doesn't work correctly because the value part has the = sign in it also.

My code doesn't work as it was assuming the value part doesnt' have an = sign in it, and it isn't using regex simply String.Split('=').

Can someone help with the regex required, I added double quotes around both the key/value to help keep things seperate.

Comment: `" I added double quotes around both the key/value to help keep things seperate"` so are the double quotes not there normally?

Comment: when you say "comma", I think you mean "semi colon".

Comment: You've provided the "given"; what's the "expected"?

Comment: http://regexpal.com/    Try using this tool with your above values.  Then you can play with the regex until it gives you the requested values.

Comment: please put in your question what your expected results should look like this will make it easier for someone to offer adequate advise / help

Comment: If you try to split what you provided on `=`, then it would also split it at `http://www.example.com?a=1`, because there's a `=` in there. I think what you really want is to split out the key/value pairs.

Comment: yes I met semi-colon.  @voithos that is why I put double qoutes around the key and values to somehow help with being able to distiguish the sections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `String.Split(char[], int)` overload (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda.aspx).  The second parameter will limit the number of substrings to return.  If you know your strings will always have at least 1 equal sign (key/value pairs), then set the second parameter to 2.

```
string x = "key1=value1 http://www.example.com?a=1;key2=value2 http://www.example.com?a=2;";
char[] equal = new char[1] { '=' };
char[] semi = new char[1] { ';' };
string[] list = x.Split(semi, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (string s in list)
{
    string[] kvp = s.Split(equal, 2);
    Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}, Value: {1}", kvp[0], kvp[1]);
}
```

-
Result:

```
Key: key1, Value: value1 http://www.example.com?a=1
Key: key2, Value: value2 http://www.example.com?a=2
```

Comment: why 2, the first = sign is what is important no, the second is in the url and should be ignored. no?

Comment: @user1361315 - because the count parameter is the maximum number of substrings to return. The key is substring 1, everything to the left of the first equal sign. Everything to the right of the first equal sign is substring 2.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't use a regex, but you could do something like the following:

```
        string test =@"""key1""=""value1 http://www.example.com?a=1"";""key2""=""value2 http://www.example.com?a=2""";

        string[] arr = test.Split(';');

        foreach (string s in arr)
        {
            int index = s.IndexOf('=');
            string key = s.Substring(0, index);

            string value = s.Substring(index+1, s.Length - index);
        }
```

Comment: The `String.Split(char[], int)` overload does all of the `IndexOf/Substring` stuff for you.

Answer (score 1):

Well what you can do, is you can use `IndexOf` to get the index of the first `=`

```
int i = myStr.IndexOf('=');
```

and then you can use the `String.Substring` to get the key and value

```
string key = myStr.Substring(0, i)

string value = myStr.SubString(i+1);
```

[Here is some documentation on the String Class that you might find useful](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wtc81z6.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You need to match not split the text

```
var keys= Regex.Matches(yourString,"""(.*?)""=.*?(http.*?)"";").Cast<Match>().Select(x=>
    new
    {
        key=x.Groups[1].Value,
        value=x.Groups[2].Value
    }
);

foreach(key in keys)
{
    key.key;//the key value
    key.value;//the value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex should look like this.

```
"(.+?)"="(.+?)"
```

Sadly I do not know `C#` but this should work in every language. To get the results you have to select for every match:

```
group(1) as keys
group(2) as values
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.Split` with `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` and an array of strings with delimiters

```
string s = "\"key1\"=\"value1 http://www.example.com?a=1\";\"key2\"=\"value2 http://www.example.com?a=2\"";

string[] result = s.Split(new string[] { "\";\"", "\"=\"", "\"" },
                           StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

---

```
result = {string[4]}
    [0]: "key1"
    [1]: "value1 http://www.example.com?a=1"
    [2]: "key2"
    [3]: "value2 http://www.example.com?a=2"
```

---

I use the following delimiters (including the double quotes):

`";"`
`"="`
`"`

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using the Split method with multiple tokens 
here this will give you a string[] of multiple values that were split out based on your tokens

if you want to remove empty Entries you could also do the code like this

```
string strValue = @"""key1""=""value1 http://www.example.com?a=1"";""key2""=""value2 http://www.example.com?a=2""";
string[] strSplit = strValue.Split(new string[] { "\";\"", "\"=\"", "\"" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Results

```
strSplit    {string[4]} string[]
[0] "key1"  
[1] "value1 http://www.example.com?a=1"
[2] "key2"  
[3] "value2 http://www.example.com?a=2"
```

Comment: Personally Chris Gessler's example works well and it utilizes .NET already built in functionality especially if you are not very comfortable using RegEx